# UltraTree - setting columns?

Tags: vb.net, ultratree

I'm using UltraTree with vb.net and I'm finding it is super easy to bind it to parent/child dataset and it populates the treeview nicely. 
However I need to hide certain columns, and I can't figure out how to do this in code. I can't use the designer since I'm using code to bind my dataset and that seems to override whatever I set in the designer as far as columns go.

Comment: Does UltraTree have a "FindNode" (or similar) method that you can use OnDataBind? I do this sort of thing with Telerik RadControls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
UltraTree1.ColumnSettings.ColumnSets(X).Columns(Y).Visible = False
```

Where X is the columnset name / index and Y is the column name / index

Comment: where would the columnset X come from? It must create it automatically since it is bound. how would I know what is X ?

Comment: If you do a debug session and do a watch on this after the UltraTree has bound to its data and see what the ColumnSets are